# Route to action in module

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I have moule admin and controller:
 backend/modules/admin/controllers/DefaultController.php

```
 public function actionIndex()
    {
        return $this->render('index');
    }

 public function actionTest()
    {
        echo "test";
    }
```

Action index called successfully:
: `http://backend/admin`

Action test return 404

Comment: What URL you're using to call this `test` action?

Comment: http://backend/admin/test

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to access the action as `app/module/controller/action` so that makes a url like
`backend/admin/default/test` as your `controller` name is `default` and not `test`. Change it and it will work.